Docker file sonar issues for file copying
Net application. I have below dockerfile.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
 
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
 
ARG NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN
ARG NUGET_USER_NAME
 
RUN dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/MAERSK-GLOBAL/index.json -n github -u $NUGET_USER_NAME -p $NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN --store-password-in-clear-text
 
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
 

COPY ["myproject/myproject.csproj", "myproject/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./myproject/./myproject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/myproject"
RUN dotnet build "./myproject.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
 
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./myproject.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
 
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myproject.dll"]

In sonar I am getting error
Make sure that recursively copying directories is safe here in the line

COPY . .

Can someone please help me to fix this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks
